# How do i make a simple graph for each correct answer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a big test coming up tomorrow, and I'm not quite sure how to draw a graph each time you get a correct answer, nor can i find/search for a good solution. Simply, I want a cavas add x height on a column/pillar for each time i answer correct, in JAVASCRIPT.

If you could show me how to do it, while using the code on this site: http://www.javascriptsource.com/miscellaneous/basic-javascript-quiz.html It would be amazing!

Edit: 
The column/piller could be something like this: (Not sure).

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,100);
```

Edit 2:

```
<script>
var score = 0;
var questions = [
    ['How many moons does Earth have?', 1],
    ['How many moons does Saturn have?',31],
    ['How many moons does Venus have?', 0]
];

for (var i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
 askQuestion(questions[i]);
}
function askQuestion(question) {
 var answer = prompt(question[0],'');
    if (answer == question[1]) {
        alert('Correct!');
        score++;
    } else {
        alert('Sorry. The correct answer is ' + question[1]);
    }
}


</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    var message = 'You got ' + score;
    message += ' out of ' + questions.length;
    message += ' questions correct.';
    document.write('<p>' + message + '</p>');
</script>

<canvas id="mycanvas"> </canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started.

Review this code and apply it to the link in your question.

Then start learning for your test!!

Given an array holding the count of correct answers for each question...

```
// an array that holds the count of correct responses for each answer

var answers=[];

for(var i=0;i<answers.length;i++){

    // how many correct answers for this question

    correctCount=answers[i];

    // make each bar 20 pixels apart on the x-axis

    answerX=i*20;

    // all bars grow from the same bottom line on the y-axis

    answerY=150;

    // all bars are the same width

    answerWidth=10;

    // each bar is 10 pixels taller for each correct answer

    answerHeight=correctCount*10;

    // draw this bar
    // a negative answerHeight will cause the bar to draw
    // upward instead of the usual downward

    ctx.fillRect(answerX,answerY,answerWidth,-answerHeight);

}
```

Comment: Didn't get it to work correctly, if you could look at edit2, which is an easier scripting for me to understand and learn it on, may you show me then?

Comment: As you might expect, I don't want to do the work for you ;-) The link to your quiz has the necessary code to ask your questions.  Combine this with the barchart code I've given above.  When done, you should have enough experience to score on your test.  Good luck tomorrow!